# Copy a subtree in the nested set model Java/MySQL

Tags: mysql, java, tree

I'm using a nested set model to represent tree folders in a program. The table structure is :
`id | lft | rft | level`

The first field is the id, the second is the left value of the nested interval, the third is the right value and the level in the tree (the level values begin from 1).
I'm using MySQL and JAVA.

The question is: **How can I copy a subtree from the tree using this model?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Make sure there is a sufficient gap in the target (you may end up renumbering the whole tree here)

b) For the top node that's moving:

```
let a = lft - lft' 
    b = level' - level
```

where lft' is the new lft for that node and level' is new level

c) a and b can now be used to determine new lft, rft and level for all nodes that's moving:

```
let lft' = lft + a
    rft' = rft + a
    level' = level + b
```